# Type mismatch when the type is already specified in scala

Tags: scala, rdd, spark-graphx

I am trying to use the code below in scala, using GraphX

```
val vertexRDD: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = graph.vertices.filter({
        case (id, (str)) => {
            val c: Boolean = scala.util.Try(str.toInt) match {
                case Success(_) => false
                case _ => true
            }
        }
    })
```

This function is with the official interface `def filter(pred: Tuple2[VertexId, VD] => Boolean): VertexRDD[VD]`

However it throws a `type mismatch` error

```
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Boolean
[error]             }
[error]             ^
```

How could it be? I have already specified the return to be `Boolean` and it is really `Boolean`, am I right?...

Comment: You have assigned the bool to `c` and an assignment will return `Unit`. To return the bool, either remove the assignment or put `c` in the last row to return it.

Comment: @Shaido: Why do you give your answer as comment? Now the question shows up as unsolved, until someone repeats your comment as answer.

Comment: @userunknown I voted to close the question as "simple typographical error", but maybe I will add it as an answer later on if it's still open & unanswered.

Comment: A typographical error? But that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this fails is that the value of a block is the value of the last expression in the block, but unfortunately the last expression in your block is a declaration which has type `Unit`. To fix this you can just remove the declaration.

You can also simplify your code by using `Try.isSuccess` and removing some unnecessary brackets

```
val vertexRDD: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = graph.vertices.filter{
    case (_, (str)) =>
        scala.util.Try(str.toInt).isSuccess        
}
```